# How to Add Image Slider with Swipe and Pinch Zoom Gestures

Tags: android, image

I have some photos in my drawable folder and I use `GalleryImageAdapter` for implementing all images in `ImageView`. But I want to add `ImageSlider` with swipe and pinch zoom gestures. I did find this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

The tutorial loads images on the sd card, but I want to load images in my drawable folder. I've tried it many times without success.

Comment: Its better to show what you have tried many times instead of saying it

Comment: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156698/how-to-get-images-dynamically-from-drawable-folder) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335189/android-how-to-show-images-from-resources-drawable) [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683501/how-to-get-the-image-from-drawable-folder-in-android) these questions may help you

Comment: try this library https://github.com/moktar/ImageSlider