# Emoji on Android Notification

Tags: android, emoji

I'm trying to display an emoji on notification bar.

Here is my string:

```
"\ue057 " + getString(R.string.notification_sent_hey)
```

I've already tried using the softbank, and every format possible: "U+1F601", "\xF0\x9F\x98\x81"

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: What's actually appearing?  Nothing?  A ? or a box?  English letters and numbers?  Something else?

Comment: \ue057 shows nothing, \xF0\x9F\x98\x81 eclipse doesn't allow to use and \u1F601 shows two weird characters

Comment: Ok, knowing Java that all makes sense.  Here's my guess-  the first one is right.  The problem is the system default font doesn't know that emoji code so it isn't appearing.  You can try changing the default font to one you know has that symbol and retry.

Comment: @GabeSechan how could I override the default font on NotificationCompat?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can.  My suggestion was to do it on the device, to make sure that was the issue.  Then we can try to solve that question.

Comment: You mean on a TextView for example?

Answer (score -3):

You can't do it like that. Notifications have a layout, and you are forced to use that layout.

A big icon, text, and a little icon. That's it. It's quite clearly stated here: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

So, you can follow the example explained here: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

For example:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event)
    .setContentTitle(eventTitle)
    .setContentText(eventLocation)
    .setLargeIcon(R.drawable.ic_event2);
    .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);

// Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// Build the notification and issues it with notification manager.
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Nothing in there would prevent him from using emoji in the text of his content or title.

Comment: So how whatsapp use emojis on the setContentText ?

Comment: You mean in the notification area? Never seen that. If you mean in a normal textView, you can use a library (this one, for example: https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon). But I think that Android doesn't support emojis out of the box (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: By the way, you can put html in TextViews. But this will only work on your own app (not in the notification bar). This is a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865452/is-it-possible-to-display-inline-images-from-html-in-an-android-textview