# Visualizing an image from Html.fromHtml in a TextView(The image must be in the server)

Tags: android, image, server

I have this problem.
I'm trying to show an image in a `TextView` in Android Studio with the method `Html.fromHtml`, but the problem is the image is in the server, so how can I do this?
There is the code:

```
TextView1.setText(Html.fromHtml(s), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
TextView1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

PS: The image is in the server because I use the `HttpUrlConnection` for get the HTML TEXT from Internet

Comment: Duplicate of :http://stackoverflow.com/a/2865947/6507689

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `Html.fromHtml` supports loading of `<img>` tags, however you're going to need to manage the way the images are fetched yourself.

Remember, this is not a web client... this is an Android app. The `fromHtml` method is really a method which interprets some html tags, and creates appropriate `Spannables` which best fit the html tags.

And so, we're back the the issue with the images (`img` tags). Again, this is not a web client. You're going to need to load the images yourself.

To do this, you need to pass to the `fromHtml` method an `ImageGetter` implementing class. See example for how to implement an `ImageGetter` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865452/is-it-possible-to-display-inline-images-from-html-in-an-android-textview).

Short version - you'll need to implement a method which accepts a string of the asset name, and returns a `Drawable` object. This method needs to be synchronous, which means you're going to need to pre-load all the image files from the server before-hand and have them ready to load when you call `fromHtml`.