# Loading an HTML file containing Images in a Textview

Tags: android, html, textview

I am using textview to load the HTML text. The HTML text has images. I am using `ImageGetter` to load images. But the image is getting cropped in the right. Below is the code:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText, new ImageGetter() {                 
@Override
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    String path = "/sdcard/" + source;
    Drawable bmp = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
    bmp.setBounds(0, 0, bmp.getIntrinsicWidth(), bmp.getIntrinsicHeight());
    return bmp; }}, null));
```

Comment: you want set drawable at center of point ?

Comment: You can use WebView instead to load the HTML content as it is, which renders the image. Still if you want to show image in TextView, refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865452/is-it-possible-to-display-inline-images-from-html-in-an-android-textview

Comment: @HemantParmar not center. But image should not crop.

Comment: I have to load in listview. As using webview in listview is not an efficient I am using textview. @GokulNathKP

Comment: Try using this lib. https://github.com/PrivacyApps/html-textview

Comment: If you simply want a bitmap in one of the sides (top, left, bottom, right - centered on that side, fully inside the view, not in the center of the View), you can use a compound drawable (or more, if you want more images - say left and right or top and bottom - or even all four).

Comment: You can use SpannableStringBuilder  for example SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append("test string ")
            .append(" ", new ImageSpan(getActivity(), R.drawable.my_icon), 0)
            .append(" okey");

    textView.setText(builder);