# TextView lags if we use many number of ImageSpan set as text in Android

Tags: android, view, textview, imageview, android-drawable

I'm using multiple ImageSpan sets to a TextView. I'm facing performance lag when the ImageSpan count increases. Is there any solution to optimize the performance with ImageSpan?

Comment: Not a good idea to use Span if you have too many images with text . have you tried setting text as HTML ? Something like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865452/is-it-possible-to-display-inline-images-from-html-in-an-android-textview)?

Comment: HTML has ImageGetter, which internally uses ImageSpan as far I checked.