# How to display HTML img tag inside Android TextView

Tags: java, android, html, kotlin

Hi I am new to  `android` development. I have a `string` which looks like this

```
String source = "Hi <b>Ram</b>. This is the Formula <img src=\"https://i.postimg.cc/wTXjVKDf/ste.png\"/> Check it Out";
```

I want to display it in `TextView`. I used

```
 textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(source, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
```

to achieve this. 
But it Looks like this
[image]

Instead of `Image`, there is a `color box showing`. I saw several questions in Stack Overflow. But all answers are outdated. Now those answers are not working. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865452/is-it-possible-to-display-inline-images-from-html-in-an-android-textview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `WebView` instead of `TextView`

```
   WebView = findViewById(R.id.WebView);
   WebView.loadData(source, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

You will get the same output.

Answer (score -1):

The textview will not be able to display images. You should use a webview.

Comment: It's possible with spannable.